# SSIS: Script to get a report from a Website

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I've trying to get a report from a Website. I have the Username and Password. When I navigate through the website set my report and download it manually. The other way that I found with the browser open copy a link like this and download the automatically:

```
https://exaple/file.csv?since=2019-08-01T00:00:00.000Z&until=2019-08-31T23:59:59.000Z.
```

I'm wondering if it's exists a C# script that I can use in SSIS with the method WebResponse or other possible Solution. I would like to automate this process with SSIS

Comment: Don't use SSIS, use something else. You're talking about web scraping here and there are any number of tools that you can use to do this.

Comment: Can you provide any Script or example?. Thanks

Comment: You coudl try `curl` or something similiar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping